# The Node Agent is stopped

Tags: websphere, connection, appserver, ibm-connections

I'm trying to start my Node on a command prompt like this:

```
C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\bin>startnode
ADMU0128I: Starting tool with the AppSrv01 profile
ADMU3100I: Reading configuration for server: nodeagent
ADMU3200I: Server launched. Waiting for initialization status.
ADMU3011E: Server launched but failed initialization. Server logs, startServer.log, and other log files under C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\nodeagent should contain failure information
```

What should I do? I try to search on how to start the node agent but it's all the same and I execute those command but it fall under the same error (noted at the top).

Here are the content of [startServer.log](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=5f08fd5f-8e3d-4237-a70c-542cc5eebc4c)

Comment: As the message from the command said, check the logs. If you can't figure it out from there, add the the relevant (error) messages from the log to your question so we can help you.

Comment: check the log file for more details.  it'll generally happen when there is a networking issue or port conflict with already existing/inuse ports

Comment: @leyrer Here are the content of startServer.log

Comment: @PaulBastide i've edited my post and i include the logs(startServer.log, systemout) i've provided a link on my post that will redirect you into those logs. "i can't attach the whole logs here that's why i make another post there" thanks!

Comment: OK, what happend between 8/15/13 and 8/16/13? Did you install any patches, ...? It worked on the 15th but did not, starting on the 16th. Something in between must have changed. Also, try starting with the "-trace" option and post the logs and trace.

Comment: @leyrer yah, thats what im confuse about because after i leave at the office its all working fine but when i open my VM the other day. all the server,node has been stopped so i try to start it but i can't

Comment: @leyrer btw i also tried starting the node on the integration solution console. i start the agentnode but it says an error "The node agent on node WIN-ETLCB8PB3T2Node01 must be started to perform the restart operation. Node agents in stopped state can not be started from the console" "node agent of WIN-ETLCB8PB3T2Node01 is "nodeagent" "

Comment: So do I understand you correctly, that a) the deploymentmanager is running, b) the node agent is not running and c) the node is not running? Are you using the windows user you always used to start the node agent?

Comment: @leyrer i'm logged as a Administrator. yup dmgr is running but the nodes are not and even the server(connections_server) i can't start it but if i can start the nodeagent i can start those. Btw i update the link above with the startServer.log -trace(see comments on the link)

Comment: My guess would be, from the updated log, that the Windows Service entry somehow got mangled. You have three services, right? One for the dmgr, one for the nodeagent and one for the server itself. If so, you could try deleting the node agent service and then try to start the nodeagent again.

Comment: @leyrer Where can i delete the node agent service?

Comment: I was having the same problem with webpshere v7.0.0.15 in a 64bit environment and this totally helped: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21508584

Answer (score 0):

[8/15/13 13:42:21:240 CST] 00000040 NodeSync      E   ADMS0005E: The system is unable to generate synchronization request: javax.management.JMRuntimeException: ADMN0022E: Access is denied for the getFolderSyncUpdates operation on CellSync MBean because of insufficient or empty credentials.

find your soap.client.props file in your profile
add in your deployment's id / pass
see if that works.

also, try stopping your node, and restarting