# WebSphere: Cannot start nodeagent/server

Tags: websphere

Can someone help me with this problem?

I'm trying to start my Node on a command prompt like this:

> C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\bin>startnode
>   ADMU0128I: Starting tool with the AppSrv01 profile
>   ADMU3100I: Reading configuration for server: nodeagent
>   ADMU3200I: Server launched. Waiting for initialization status.
>   ADMU3011E: Server launched but failed initialization. Server logs, startServer.log, and other log files under 
> C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\nodeagent should contain failure information

What should i do? I try to search on how to start the node agent but its all the same and i execute those command but it fall under the same error(noted at the top).

Btw you can also refer on my other topic for other information such as serverlogs thanks! [Here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=5f08fd5f-8e3d-4237-a70c-542cc5eebc4c)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [The Node Agent is stopped](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18266684/the-node-agent-is-stopped)

Answer (score 2):

You must check the log files in the profile directory to determine the cause of the startup failure.

The default profile log directory location is here:

/IBM/WebSphere/WAS8/AppServer/profiles/*YourProfile*/logs/server1

Under the directory -> /profiles/*YourProfile*/logs/server1

```
You will find a couple of logfiles:
startServer.log 
SystemErr.log
SystemOut.log
+ some other log interesting files.
```

You may also have a look at the log files under -> /profiles/*YourProfile*/logs/ffdc
where you will find logs containing information about non handled faults.

Answer (score 0):

If the server worked before but suddenly stopped then one possibility is that your osgi cache is broken for some reason. I found that those commands help:
Step to resolve the "ADMU3011E" error. Solution for windows Let WPS_HOME = C:\IBM\WebSphere
Step (1): Go to command prompt
Step (2): cd \wp_profile\bin
Step (3): execute file "osgiCfgInit.bat" at command prompt
Now your server should start up again.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that the permissions are off somehow. I had that issue on Linux. May be someone started the nodeagent/servers as root and so starting the nodeagent as the appropriate user creates an issue with being able to write to a log file or something. In my case, there were no errors in the nodeagent logs directory at all.

To fix the perms, recursively set the owner for your WebSphere directory and any logs directories outside that directory if you have any.

```
chown -R *user:group* /IBM/WebSphere/
chown -R *user:group* /IBM/logs/
```

(If `/IBM/logs/` is where your logs are, for example.)

Updating the ownership did it for me.